# Benzylic and allylic carbocation stability order

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

Most books I have read stop at this order : 
Benzylic > Allylic > Tertiary > secondary > primary 
 
However If I want to compare tertiary, secondary and primary benzylic and Allylic carbocations what will be their stability order?

Comment: Tertiary benzylic carbocations should be stabilised more due the $+M$ effect of three benzylic groups. The same should apply for allylic carbocations.

Comment: Should the answer then be tertiary benzylic>Secondary benzylic>primary benzylic> tertiary Allylic > secondary allylic> primary Allylic > tertiary> primary> secondary

Comment: Yes, seems correct to me.

Comment: Yeah that "seems" to be correct but I saw one problem where they said that teritary carbonation can be more stable than primary allylic because of a lot of hydrogens that take part in hyperconjugation in the outweighs the mesomeric effect

Comment: There is no simple general rule for this. The rules you state are also not "absolute".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by tertiary benzylic etc. Do you mean three phenyl groups (trityl cation) or one phenyl group and two alkyl groups?

Answer (score 1):

Yes tertiary allyllic carbocation is more stable than secondary because no.  of electrone donating methyl groups are greater than secondary (in tertiary 3 methyl groups  while in secondary  are 2) so they decrease  electrophilicity carbocation but it still it remain electrophillic.